# Why do I get inconsistent spaces over and under buttons text depending on the type of device (desktop or mobile) with Orbitron font family?

Tags: android, html, ios, css

I'm having quite an issue at the moment. I get different spaces over and under my buttons text which varies if I use a desktop/laptop or a mobile/tablet.

When I inspect a button on desktops and laptops (on any browser), I can see that there is some type of "white space" over and under the text, but it is not a problem because the spaces are even. (See the screenshot below, the text is vertically aligned correctly)

[View on a desktop/laptop resized window (Google Chrome)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1Gtb.jpg)

However, on mobiles, tablets and Macs (on any browser), there is only a "white space" under the text and not over it, so the text gets pushed towards the top of the button (see screenshot below).

[View on a mobile (Samsung Galaxy S6, Google Chrome)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISjQX.jpg)

If I uncheck the Orbitron google font in the inspector, the default font seems to be aligned correctly.

Is there a work around to this font glitch (it seems to be one) ?

Here's this particular button's CSS code :

```
cursor: pointer;
font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
font-size: 2.1vw;
font-weight: 700;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #0b0b0b;
background-color: white;
border-style: none;
padding: 0.2em 0;
width: 83%;
box-shadow: 0 0.2em 0.8em 0 #0b0b0b;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
-o-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
-webkit-transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Not sure all your inherited styles, but maybe look at your `line-height`. Also, your `font-size` is based on `vw` which could affect other sizing elements because of the dynamic widths of the viewport.

Comment: Thanks for your reply dward, I forgot to specify that I also experimented with an em based font-size and logical (and some unlogical) line-height values. Still no success unfortunately...

Comment: If you provide a fiddle with all CSS, that would be helpful for me or anyone else.

Comment: I don't have a solution, but as a workaround you could try setting the line-height to 0 and then fine tuning the top and bottom padding.

Comment: @dward There you go. If you test it on your laptop/desktop, the text will look perfectly centered vertically, but if you test it on your mobile/tablet or even a Mac, it will look off (closer from the top).

http://jsfiddle.net/n0tyrua6/2/